what css to make react flip number like example
I use react flip number from here github.com/beekai-oss/react-flip-numbers the result like this 
but I want to make it like this with some space between number.I want to ask what CSS can I write to make it look like this picture? 
 type visitortype={
      count: number;
    }


const Footer = () => {
  const [visitor, setvisitor] = useState<visitortype>();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://count.cab/hit/ghG6Oirn0b')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(allvisitor=>  setvisitor(allvisitor))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }, []);

 return (
    <GridItem
      w="100%"
      h={{ base: "80px", lg: "300px" }}
      colSpan={{ base: 8, lg: 4 }}
    >
      <VStack
        align={{ base: "center", lg: "stretch" }}
        marginTop={{ base: "0", lg: "60px" }}
        marginLeft={{ base: "0", lg: "50px" }}
      >
        <Box w={{ base: "100px", lg: "220px" }} paddingBottom={"10px"}>
          <Image src={imgLogoMd} alt="Logo" w="100%" />
          <HStack>

             <FlipNumbers 
          height={25} 
           width={20}  
           color="white" 
           background="#8D0000"
           numberStyle={{
            fontSize: 16,
          }}
           play perspective={100} 
           numbers={`${visitor?.count ?? 0}`}/>;

          </HStack>
        </Box>
      </VStack>
    </GridItem>
  );

};


Does this answer your question? Style for visitor counter React.js
